# Use one of two dates in where clause

Tags: sql, date, where-clause

I need to delete all records in a table where the CreatedDate or ModifiedDate is greater than x. The logic is as follows:

- If ModifiedDate is not null then use this value
- Otherwise use the CreatedDate value

Not applying the if/else statement correctly.

```
delete * from table where
-- how to implement the following
if ModifiedDate is not null then ModifiedDate < GETDATE() - 30
else CreatedDate < GETDATE() - 30
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Date functions work differently in different makes and versions of SQL table server. Please [edit] your tags to tell us which one you use.

Comment: Please read this - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/case-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15. it will help you to right proper expression.

Comment: You say greater than but your sample code checks for less than?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this where clause:

```
where coalesce(ModifiedDate, CreateDate) < dateadd(day, -30, getdate())
```

Comment: Thank you!  Worked out great.

Comment: You could accept the answer if it helped.

Answer (score 0):

Use case statment

```
Delete * From tableX
CASE WEHN  ModifiedDate is not null and < Getdate() - 30 THEN -- your logic
Else -- CreateDate < Getdate() - 30 END
```